# Convert from MySQL datetime to another format with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a `datetime` column in MySQL.

How can I convert it to the display as **mm/dd/yy H:M (AM/PM)** using PHP?

Comment: What we need to know is how the date is stored within the SQL. Is it Timestamp or Datetime or unixtime?

Comment: They are stored not in unix time, just like a normal date, PHP is the one that deal with it as seconds and stuff. I would recommend you to use the PHP `OOP` datetime functions, they are very easy to use.

Comment: Can I recommend and alternative to your date format? `mm/dd/yy` is very American, and those of us living in other parts of the world get more than a little irritable on trying to second-guess what is meant by `11-12-13`. The more universal standard is `yyyy-mm-dd`, and is part of the ISO 8601 standard. Failing that, you should use the month _name_, not the number.

Answer (score 569, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to normalize a date into MySQL format, use the following

```
$phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );
```

The line `$phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate )` accepts a string and performs a series of heuristics to turn that string into a unix timestamp.

The line `$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate )` uses that timestamp and PHP's [`date`](http://php.net) function to turn that timestamp back into MySQL's standard date format.

(**Editor Note**: This answer is here because of an original question with confusing wording, and the general Google usefulness this answer provided even if it didnt' directly answer the question that now exists)

Comment: this answer is confusing the topic

Comment: 'Y-m-d H:i:s' is the correct standard datetime format (read the MySQL manual, all example use this format)

Comment: @0xBAADF00D: please read the question again...nobody asked about the MySQL standard format.

Comment: of course, but, when standard exist, it could be nice to follow standard (it avoid headache later when another dev work on your code) xD

Comment: Can you please say me what will be the preg_match for "m/d/y g:i:s" ?

Comment: The question asks to output in the format mm/dd/yy H:M (AM/PM), not "Y-m-d H:i:s".

Comment: `does not work` for who? Accepted answer will work if you want to convert ***from*** MySQL into **mm/dd/yy H:M (AM/PM)** as OP requested. Just because you want to do the opposite does not make accepted answer wrong.

Comment: Use this to convert English user input Date to save as proper MySQL.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This issue has plagued me for quite some time.  So nice to see such a simple example.

Comment: and 'Y-m-d H:i:s' is not a constant somewhere?

Answer (score 324):

To convert a date retrieved from MySQL into the format requested (`mm/dd/yy H:M (AM/PM)`):

```
// $datetime is something like: 2014-01-31 13:05:59
$time = strtotime($datetimeFromMysql);
$myFormatForView = date("m/d/y g:i A", $time);
// $myFormatForView is something like: 01/31/14 1:05 PM
```

Refer to the [PHP date formatting options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) to adjust the format.

Comment: Where is this `$row` object supposed to be from?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think some of you are missing the point. He wants the output to be in "m/d/y g:i A" format, pulling the original date from a DATETIME field. So his code works. @Mike $row->createdate is just Tim's datetime column.

Comment: @AsTeR answer is only confusing if you misread the question. OP answered own question and wants to take a date ***from*** MySQL and output to requested format: **mm/dd/yy H:M (AM/PM)**.

Comment: @TimBoland I think answer could be improved if ***from*** was emphasized as well as the requested format **mm/dd/yy H:M (AM/PM)**. And it could benefit from a link to the date function. I tried to [suggest an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4325627), but it was rejected.

Comment: @toxalot and of course, we all read the whole question three times before jumping to copy paste the answer code ;)

Comment: Fun fact: this answer is roughly equivalent to the one just below (which has virtually no downvotes), but it got >40 downvotes because it answers the OP's question, which differs from that which people who come to this page actually have.

Comment: Use this to output DateTime from MySql to eg. web page in ~English format.

Answer (score 117):

If you are using PHP 5, you can also try

```
$oDate = new DateTime($row->createdate);
$sDate = $oDate->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: As stated above in comments, the standard format is `("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

Answer (score 48):

```
$valid_date = date( 'm/d/y g:i A', strtotime($date));
```

**Reference:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I think people downvote because they are confused about OP question. Most read the question to be the opposite of what it actually is. The other possibility is that this is very similar to accepted answer that was posted 5+ years ago.

Comment: The link you reference does not point to the function you are using, nor does it explain the format. I think http://php.net/function.date.php would be better.

Comment: @toxalot The accepted answer is wrong. It edited after my answer & about my link i replace your link. Thanks

Comment: This whole Q&A has a sordid history. The accepted answer ***was*** wrong between April 29, 2013 and May 24, 2013. It was correct when you first posted your answer. Your answer ***was*** wrong until May 29, 2013, after which it became very similar to accepted answer.

Answer (score 34):

Finally the right solution for PHP 5.3 and above:
*(added optional Timezone to the Example like mentioned in the comments)*

without time zone:

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $mysql_source_date);
echo $date->format('m/d/y h:i a');
```

with time zone:

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $mysql_source_date, new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
echo $date->format('m/d/y h:i a');
```

Comment: its error.. Class 'App\Controller\DateTime' not found ..using php 6.4

Comment: If you are working in another namespace, you have to call it with a backslash in front of it: `\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $mysql_source_date);`

Comment: Don't forget to specify the timezone when you create your date object! Otherwise, your formatted date might be several hours off. Your `datetime` columns should be UTF8, so pass `new DateTimeZone('UTC')` as the 3rd parameter to ensure PHP knows.

Comment: This is the correct answer that outputs the OP's desired format, just take care of timezones

Answer (score 10):

An easier way would be to format the date directly in the MySQL query, instead of PHP.  See the [MySQL manual entry for DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

If you'd rather do it in PHP, then you need the [date](http://uk.php.net/date) function, but you'll have to convert your database value into a timestamp first.

Comment: -1 because formatting date in DB is not good idea. Multilanguage web need different date formats and then you have to format date in PHP (business logic language in common).
When you wrote about `date` function, then you should wrote about `strottime` function also to help someone instead of "but you'll have to convert your database value into a timestamp first".

Answer (score 10):

Forget all. Just use:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$date)))
```

Answer (score 9):

This should format a field in an SQL query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( `fieldname` , '%d-%m-%Y' ) FROM tablename
```

Comment: You should specify *MySQL* query, not just SQL, because that won't necessarily work with all databases. While OP asked for PHP solution, this is a good alternative that OP may not have known about. However, this will not provide the requested format. To get the format OP requested, you'd need `'%m/%d/%y %h:%i %p'`.

Answer (score 9):

To correctly format a `DateTime` object in PHP for storing in MySQL use the standardised format that MySQL uses, which is [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

PHP has had this format stored as a constant since version 5.1.1, and I highly recommend using it rather than manually typing the string each time.

```
$dtNow = new DateTime();
$mysqlDateTime = $dtNow->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

This, and a list of other PHP DateTime constants are available at http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types

Comment: MySQL doesn't actually use this format, and MySQL generates a warning if you include the "+xxxx" time zone designator that gets generated by it.

UPDATE X SET Y = '2014-03-31T15:00:00+0100' where Z;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 1

Comment: OP wants to take a date ***from*** MySQL format and convert *to* **mm/dd/yy H:M (AM/PM)**.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [date](http://www.php.net/date) function:

```
<?php
    echo date("m/d/y g:i (A)", $DB_Date_Field);
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't the date() function expect an integer timestamp rather than a datetime specified in the question?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your MySQL datetime configuration. Typically: ***2011-12-31 07:55:13*** format. This very simple function should do the magic:

```
function datetime()
{
    return date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
}

echo datetime(); // display example: 2011-12-31 07:55:13
```

Or a bit more advance to match the question.

```
function datetime($date_string = false)
{
    if (!$date_string)
    {
        $date_string = time();
    }
    return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date_string));
}
```

Comment: This does not answer OP question. OP wants to take a date *from* MySQL format and convert *to* **mm/dd/yy H:M (AM/PM)**. Plus this will just format current time, not a specific date.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT 
 DATE_FORMAT(demo.dateFrom, '%e.%M.%Y') as dateFrom,
 DATE_FORMAT(demo.dateUntil, '%e.%M.%Y') as dateUntil
FROM demo
```

If you dont want to change every function in your PHP code, to show the expected date format, change it at the source - your database.

It is important to name the rows with the **as** operator as in the example above (as dateFrom, as dateUntil). The names you write there are the names, the rows will be called in your result.

The output of this example will be

[Day of the month, numeric (0..31)].[Month name (January..December)].[Year, numeric, four digits]

Example: 5.August.2015

Change the dots with the separator of choice and check the [DATE_FORMAT(date,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function for more date formats.

Answer (score 4):

You can also have your query return the time as a Unix timestamp. That would get rid of the need to call `strtotime()` and make things a bit less intensive on the PHP side...

```
select  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timsstamp) as unixtime from the_table where id = 1234;
```

Then in PHP just use the `date()` function to format it whichever way you'd like.

```
<?php
  echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', $row->unixtime);
?>
```

or

```
<?php
  echo date('F j, Y, g:i a', $row->unixtime);
?>
```

I like this approach as opposed to using [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)'s `DATE_FORMAT` function, because it allows you to reuse the same query to grab the data and allows you to alter the formatting in PHP.

It's annoying to have two different queries just to change the way the date looks in the UI.

Comment: I like the idea of using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` to eliminate the need for `strtotime`. This answer would be better if it gave an example of formatting the time in the format OP actually requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can have trouble with dates not returned in Unix Timestamp, so this works for me...

```
return date("F j, Y g:i a", strtotime(substr($datestring, 0, 15)))
```

Comment: This does not convert the date to format requested by OP.

Answer (score 1):

This will work...

```
echo date('m/d/y H:i (A)',strtotime($data_from_mysql));
```

Comment: That format mixes 24 time with AM/PM. Otherwise, it is the same as accepted answer that was posted 5+ years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Direct output e.g. in German format:

```
  echo(date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime($row["date_added"])));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP version 4.4.9 & MySQL 5.0, this worked for me:

```
$oDate = strtotime($row['PubDate']);
$sDate = date("m/d/y",$oDate);
echo $sDate
```

`PubDate` is the column in [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL).

Comment: This does not convert the date to format requested by OP

Answer (score -1):

```
$date = "'".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $_POST['date'])))."'";
```

Comment: This does not answer OP question. OP wants to take a date *from* MySQL format and convert *to* **mm/dd/yy H:M (AM/PM)**. This does the opposite. Plus it takes input from a form rather than the database.