# Getting a PHP DateTime object into a string representation of a MYSQL date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a DateTime which I want to store in a Date MySQL column. I am using MySQLi and prepared statements.

When binding parameters, I cannot specify date as a type, only strings and integers.

How do I convert the DateTime to a MySQL date string representation? There is very little documentation on the DateTime class.

Comment: Almost closed this as a duplicate question, then I realized it was different and I reopened it.  Please excuse my haste!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I almost closed this as a duplicate of [Convert from MySQL datetime to another format with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/format-mysql-datetime-with-php) but I think it's actually the reverse problem.  That question asked how to format a date fetched from MySQL, and you're asking how to format a date for input to a query.

**Option 1:**

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DateTimeCol = ?
```

You can format the value to the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` format MySQL wants:

```
<?php $mysql_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp); ?>
```

Then submit it as a string parameter to the query.

**Option 2:**

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DateTimeCol = FROM_UNIXTIME(?)
```

Then you can submit the timestamp value as a numeric parameter to the query.

**Option 3:**

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DateTimeCol = STR_TO_DATE(?, '%m/%d/%y')
```

You can submit a wide variety of string representations of date/time, if you specify the formatting to MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.  For the formatting codes, see the [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

Comment: Second are optional, but yes that works.  If you use 'H' (12-hour clock) instead of 'G' (24-hours clock), then you should also include AM/PM.  Refer to DATE_FORMAT() documentation for full list of codes.

Comment: 'h' is 12-hour clock, 'H' is 24 with leading zeros and 'G' is 24 without leading zeros.

You should indeed use 'H'.

Comment: I've edited the format string in option 1 above with respect to these comments from ʞɔıu and christian studer.

Answer (score 1):

Because the DateTime-class introduced with PHP5 is poorly documented, i wouldn't recommend to use it. I find regular timestamps to be much easier to work with!

But if you still want to use DateTime-objects, a solution would be to transform the objects into (unix) timestamps before storing them in your database. Transform the timestamps back to DateTime-objects after reading information from your database.

To create DateTime-object from a timestamp, use [date_create()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) with the timestamp as argument. To get your objects representation of number of seconds since the Unix Epoch, use [date_format($object, 'U')](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php) (uppercase U).