# which character should i use for dateTime (for example for int we use %d)

Tags: c#

when we want to pass sth to database like `int` we use(%d) like below

`...string.format("select * from Table where code=%d",100)...`

what should i use instead of `%d` when we want to pass `dateTime` ?

Comment: Where do you even find `string.format` in .NET? Especially with C format strings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a PHP DateTime object into a string representation of a MYSQL date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396610/getting-a-php-datetime-object-into-a-string-representation-of-a-mysql-date)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dont use string.format() for db parameter substitution, you end up in SQL injection. SqlCommand has Parameters property , you can add the parameters into the collection

use parameterized query like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourParam",value);
```

more efficient if you use the Using block with your code.

like this

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnString"))
using(SqlCommand cmd =  new SqlCommand(con))
{
   // do some stuffs. like add parameters. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Ravi's answer.

You should avoid concatenating your SQL queries like that, because it will allow for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

In your case, I would consider using an ORM ([Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx), [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)), but if you just want to use the `SqlCommand`, your query would look somewhat like this:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("your connectionstring goes here"))
{
    using(var command = new SqlCommand("select* from Table where code=@dateTime", 
                                                                             connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTime", DateTime.Now);

        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    }
}
```

Here's an example from wikipedia that shows the problem with concatenating the sql statement:

`statement = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '" + userName + "';"`

What happens if `userName` contains just a `'`?

The final SQL statement will then look like this:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '''`

Which is incorrect and will thrown an error. By exposing this, you can do Very harmfull things to your data!