# PHP Date Conversion

Tags: php, date, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format mysql datetime with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/format-mysql-datetime-with-php)

How to convert the following:

```
2010-12-07 12:00:00
```

into:

```
December, 7th, 2010
```

Comment: *(reference)* http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: There will always be people who spoonfeed even the laziest questions. Wonderful, five identical answers. Bleh. Just what this place needs. Yet [another how to format date question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+format+date+php)

Comment: @Gordon: It's the fastest way to get rep :)

Comment: This question really does duplicate over 15 other incarnations of the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
echo date("F, jS, Y", strtotime("2010-12-07 12:00:00"));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
$myDate = strtotime('2010-12-07 12:00:00');
$formattedDate = date('F, jS, Y', $myDate)
```

Comment: Odd to call a timestamp myDate

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's what happens when you take 2 seconds instead of 3 to write a response. I suppose the same could be said of @Dutchie432's response using `$d` instead of `$t` and @John Giotta's response using the same exact naming convention as mine.

Comment: Matt is right... The same could be said about my post. With quick one-shot calculations like that, I see no reason why the original variable can't reflect that it will end up being used to calculate a date. In my case, `d` stands for `aDateWillBeCalculatedUsingThisTimestampWhichIsNotInDateFormatYet`

Answer (score 3):

Use date_format

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php

```
$date = date_create('2010-12-07 12:00:00');
echo date_format($date, 'F, jS, Y');
```

Answer (score 3):

`echo date('F, jS, Y',strtotime('2010-12-07 12:00:00'));`

Answer (score 3):

```
$d = strtotime('2010-12-07 12:00:00');
echo date('F, jS, Y', $d);
```