# How to convert PHP time into read able form?

Tags: php, sql, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format mysql datetime with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/format-mysql-datetime-with-php)

Well.. I have stored date(c) in Mysql DB and the data type i used in varchar. So it is stored in format 2012-07-01T22:03:02+05:30 .
well it kinda look difficult to read.

can anyone help me how to convert it into something like  July 1,2012 at 10:03 PM

Comment: for the day you could just use a substring and slice it to an array on `-`.

Comment: It's not really a duplicate because Prakash seems to want to reformat a regular varchar string - but this problem would definitely be better solved by using a datetime or timestamp field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php.net/date
php.net/strtotime

```
date( "F d, Y \a\t g:i a", strtotime( $databaseValue ) );
```

Comment: Meh, I still voted to close with you.  In the meantime, take the freebie.  :P

Comment: Ok, I misspoke then.  I flagged it.  Freebie = answering an easy question.  There's not many questions that I can answer on here.  :P

Comment: date( "F d, Y \a\t g:i a", strtotime( $databaseValue ) );
it works but it is like
July 01, 2012 a  10:00 pm

i think /a is working but /t is not

Comment: Try just \at without the second slash

Answer (score 1):

You can still use MySQL date functions  - mysql will implicitly cast them to date.

Say you have a table bla, and a field "mydate" of varchar, then just use the following SQL:

```
select date_format(mydate, '%M %e, %Y at %l:%i %p') as my_formatted_date from bla
```

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.3:

```
$dateMySQL = '2012-07-01T22:03:02+05:30';
$inputFormat = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP';
$outputFormat = 'F j,Y \a\t h:i A';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($inputFormat, $dateMySQL);
echo $date->format($outputFormat);
```

which will print "July 1,2012 at 10:03 PM".