# Date format issue in printing

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format mysql datetime with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/format-mysql-datetime-with-php)

I have this query:

```
$sql="SELECT job_id,job,job2,start_date,end_date ".
     "FROM pianificazione WHERE job_id='$selected_jobs'";
```

the end-date is in a DATE format in the database, but i need to print it in d-m-Y format
Here is where i print it:

```
echo "<td><input type='text'id='end_date'  class='datepicker'  ".
         "title='D-MMM-YYYY' name='end_date[$i]' value='".
          $rows['end_date']. "' /></td>";
```

Could you please help me with this?
Thanks..

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Check this.. $mydate = strtotime($row->createdate);
$dateis = date("m/d/y g:i A", $mydate);

Answer (score 4):

You can directly use in mysql query

```
DATE_FORMAT(end_date,'%d-%m-%Y')
```

**Updated:**

```
DATE_FORMAT(end_date,'%d-%m-%Y') as end_date
```

Comment: @Tao fetch using NUM instead of ASSOC will solve the problem, or probably you can create an alias.

Comment: use alias name in your query `DATE_FORMAT(end_date,'%m-%d-%Y') as end_date`

Comment: Tao was looking for `d-m-Y` btw, not for `m-d-Y`...

Comment: Now you changed it to `d-d-Y`...

Answer (score 0):

To convert your DATE format $date to a `d-m-Y` format date use PHPs [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) function like this:

```
$date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));
```

Comment: to me, I prefer it to be done in the query instead

Comment: I tend to keep my queries as clean and short as possible, doing such minor things rather in PHP then inflating your query.

Answer (score -3):

```
$date = substr($date_original, 8, 2).'-'.substr($date_original, 5, 2).'-'.substr($date_original, 0, 4);
```