# Re-Arrange the format of a date stored in a Variable

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to re-structure the format of a date that is stored in a variable.
I retrieve the date/time from an MySQL database stored as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS and I am using PHP.

I would like to display the date as

Thu 2nd Mar 2013 2:30pm

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Wow. I am pretty google can help you. Or the PHP docs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format mysql datetime with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/format-mysql-datetime-with-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please look into these date formats.
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

And using this php code (I've not putted down the right format yet!)

```
$datetime = strtotime($mysqldatevalue);
$mysqldate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $datetime);
```

Comment: No, put the `mysql` value into the `strtotime` function and you will see, don't forget to edit the format with the URL posted.

Comment: Thanks it works except if you should write Y-m-d as it doubles if you write YY-mm-dd. Will accept answer in 6mins :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Use strtotime() to change the SQL date into a unix timestamp, then feed that as the second parameter to date() along with the appropriate [format string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 0):

`date("d/m/Y H:i:s",strtotime($time_from_db))` will convert `2012-01-01 10:12:14` to `01/01/2012 10:12:14`, you can replace the first parameter the fit what you need from the specifications in the [date function in php site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($dbdate));
```

You can also to this directly in your query:

```
DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as date
```

Answer (score 0):

Even you can use this: since you mentioned:

> ***I would like to display the date as
>   Thu 2nd Mar 2013 2:30pm
>   Is this possible?***

Query: syntax: `'%a %D %b %Y %r'`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2013-03-02 14:30:00',
               '%A %D %b %Y %r');



 | DATE_FORMAT('2013-03-02 14:30:00',
               '%A %D %B %Y %R') |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                        Sat 2nd Mar 2013 02:30:00 PM |
```

Comment: @user1993796 at first I looked at your 2.30pm, it seems you don't mind the seconds, hence take a look at this as well ;) By the way 2nd March 2013 is a Saturday..