# I'm trying to add a sign up date into mysql based on the post timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This works for me but it adds the datetime in mysql as 1970 01 01 00:00 00

```
include("mysql_connect.php");
$phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );

//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO people (username, email, sign_up_date) VALUES ('$_POST[username]','$_POST[usermail]', '" . $mysqldate . "'  )";

if (!mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Here's my html form:

```
<section class="loginform tmr">
<form name="login" action="regi.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label for="username">Username: </label><br />
        <input type="username" name="username" placeholder="Handle" required><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="sign_up_date" value="<?php echo $_POST['sign_up_date'] ?>">
    <label for="usermail">Email: </label><br />
        <input type="email" name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required><br />
    <label for="password">Password: </label><br />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</section>
```

I'm using a hidden input and requesting the post value.

I tried using `timesteamp()` and `date()`

sign_up_date type in mysql is datetime..

should i use something like this?

```
$insertdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['Date']));
```

Additionally, I have a field called account_permissions enum('a', 'b', 'c') and I'm wondering how I insert that into my form (should i use another hidden input)... I need it to default to 'a' all the time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/format-mysql-datetime-with-php

Comment: Wait, you're generating the date in PHP, outputting that to the page, sending it back via a form to then populate a column in a new row instead of just using `NOW()` in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `sign_up_date` column data type is `DATE`, you can just use the MySQL [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) function:

```
INSERT INTO people (username, email, sign_up_date)
  VALUES ('name', 'email', CURDATE())
```

Remember that a `DATE` column will store just the date, without the time of day. If you want to include the time of day accurate to seconds, make it a `DATETIME` column and populate it with `NOW()` instead of `CURDATE()`. If you want to include the time of day accurate to fractions of a second, make it a `TIMESTAMP` column and populate it with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

**IMPORTANT:** note that the point behind mysqli is to avoid using expressions like `... VALUES ('$_POST[username]', ...`, which leave you open to SQL Injection attacks. See [here](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) for more information, and please follow their guidelines - SQL Injection is a very real threat.

Comment: NOW worked brilliantly. Thank you for the explanation and help. I'll mark this as the correct answer when the time allows me to.

Comment: Can you help me with the second part of the question... for instance if i want the default account permissions to be a 'c' or 'b'.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't completely understand that part of the question, but here's a general answer: If you define the column as "not null" - `account_permissions enum('a', 'b', 'c') NOT NULL` - and insert a row without specifying the `account_premissions` value, MySQL will automatically set it to the first `enum` value (`a`), so you don't really need to do anything from the PHP side.

Comment: I'm not quite sure i understand the information on that link you provided. Those are prepared statements?

Comment: It's defaulting to `a` correct. How to I make it default to a different permission like b or c?

Comment: Regarding the link - yes, those are prepared statements. The examples are decent, but mysqli has a bit of a learning curve. Worth it, though. You can Google for other examples. As for defaulting to a different permission, do you mean all the time or do you mean under certain circumstances?

Comment: defaulting all the time.

Comment: To default all the time, one easy way would be to change the `enum` definition. For example, if you wanted to default to `b` all the time then you could define the column as `account_permissions enum('b', 'a', 'c') NOT NULL`. Or to make it more obvious (always a good thing), define the column as `account_permissions enum('a', 'b', 'c') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'b'`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing doesn't make sense. You're generating the date in PHP, outputting that to the page, sending it back via a form to then reformat and use in SQL. What's wrong with [NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO people (username, email, sign_up_date) 
    VALUES ('$_POST[username]','$_POST[usermail]', NOW() )";
```

You could even just set the default value of that column to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` and not have to send it

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO people (username, email) 
    VALUES ('$_POST[username]','$_POST[usermail]' )";
```

**Please note your SQL is open to injection as you are not sanitizing the $_POSTs**

Comment: Thanks for helping out too, i know you mentioned using NOW() in your original comment. I didn't know about that function. Should i still be using the hidden input to $_POST['sign_up_date']

Answer (score 0):

Check here the datetime format and create it from the timestamp you get with time()
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Alternatively you can store date in timestamp

About enum you can add a selectbox with these three values.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `people` MODIFY COLUMN `sign_up_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Running this query once to alter your table and removing everything inside your php code related to sign_up_date field should solve all your problems. Basically this means when you insert a new record mysql will automatically assign current date value to sign_up_date field as default value.