# how to echo out 12 hour time format in my page

Tags: php, mysql

please i need your help i created a comment box in my page, stored inside phpmyadmin with time type DATETIME. the problem am having is the time always display in 24 hour format and i want it to display in 12 hour format (PM/AM) and be stored inside mysql. i have tried using `date()` function at the same time i used `date("y-m-d H:i:s")` instead of `now())`function but the result i keep on getting is in 24 hour format 
see the code

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (name,comment,whenadded) VALUE ('$name','$comment', now())");
```

With this code i get the result in 24 hour time format.

`whenadded` is the DATETIME variable name.

thank you in advance.

Comment: A format will help (at least my eyes) ç_ç

Comment: Store it in MySQL as it is, and use the application (PHP) to display it in the format you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format MySQL datetime with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/format-mysql-datetime-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

You want to store the date as DATETIME in the MySQL DB, thats good practice.

For output, use PHP's date() function. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/format-mysql-datetime-with-php). Or you use MySQLs [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

```
SELECT date_format(whenadded, 'Y-m-d h:i') AS my_date FROM ...
```

Comment: Give OP also an option to format datetime in MySQL, using `DATE_FORMAT()` function.

Comment: @aebersold tnx but pls am i gonna insert it like this echo date_format(whenadded, 'Y-m-d h:i') AS my_date FROM test

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. 1. Store the date as DATETIME in the DB. 2. Format the output, with the examples I provided.

Answer (score 0):

The php documentation should help http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

what you are looking of is `date(y-m-d g:i a)` wich will give something like "2013-12-30 4:38 pm"

Comment: you are correct that's what i want, but how can it be stored in mysql. you know if i output this date(y-m-d g:i a) it will keep on updating when ever i refresh my page. which i dnt want it to be so, cause it is a comment box. pls help me out. tanx allot

Answer (score 0):

Let the mysql decide its date format, it's mostly irrelevant for you.

What you need, is to properly format your output data, like:

```
echo date("y-m-d h:i:s A", strtotime($date));
```

Where `$date` is the variable you get from MySQL.

Comment: @AHAPEN 311 tnx it works but the result i keep on getting is 70-01-01 1:00 am. it keep on repeating same thing

Answer (score 0):

In no particular order:

- phpMyAdmin is not a database engine. MySQL is.
- Dates are not stored in any particular format. You give format when you convert them to strings.
- The mysql_... legacy extension is deprecated, insecure, triggers a notice in latest PHP versions and will be removed.
- Your code is probably vulnerable to SQL Injection.
- The [H format code](http://php.net/date) means: *24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros*.

Answer (score -3):

It's good to save the data within 24Hours Format, but you can show it within 12Hours plus am/pm

```
date("d/m/Y - g:i A");
```

Comment: Please provide the OP with how if possible.

Comment: Edited as you've suggested