# Formatting a date from mysql date time to normal standard format

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-formatting

I have this in my html for a result

```
<?php echo $row['end_date']?>
```

that results in **2014-01-31 22:00:00**

I want it to echo this format

**01/31/14 10:00pm** OR **January 31, 2014 10pm** if possible

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: here is a useful answers , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/format-mysql-datetime-with-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) is incredible for this.

You just need to create a DateTime object with the string that MySQL returns, and it will parse it automatically. Then, just call the [DateTime::format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method to format it the way you want.

```php
<?php
$date = new DateTime($row['end_date']); // e.g. 2014-01-31 22:00:00
echo $date->format(DateTime::RFC2822); // result: Fri, 31 Jan 2014 22:00:00 +0100
echo $date->format('F j, Y g:ia'); // result: January 31, 2014 10:00pm
?>
```

For formatting the date, see the manual for the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this.

https://www.php.net/strtotime

Many other options are available to format the date the way you want.

Thanks
Amit