# date formatting from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a serious problem dealing with data from MySQL. 
I insert the date upon form submission via php using NOW() and it is inserted into a 
table with field date. Upon retrieval from the db, I will like to subtract from a given 
say 10 hours, and once at zero a function is executed.
But my conversion does not seem to work as I keep getting errors.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

code:

```
//retrieval from db
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `objectives` LIMIT 0 , 30");

while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
  $data['obj_date'];//2014-04-06
  echo date('Y-d')- $data['obj_date'];//0
}
```

Comment: you cannot use "-" for dates , they are not numbers . take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/convert-from-mysql-datetime-to-another-format-with-php) for converting that to php date and [diff function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) to get the difference.

Answer (score 1):

try it like this, as you can't subtract 2 dates as you're doing in php you have to use `strtotime` to change the dates into timestamps, then you subtract these 2, then you calculate what you want to get...

```
<?php
//$data['obj_date'];//2014-04-06
//Difference in seconds
$difference=strtotime(date("Y-m-d")) - strtotime($data['obj_date']);
//Calculate number of days
echo ($difference/86400).' days';
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Code:

```
$date = date('h:i:s A', strtotime($data['obj_date'])-36000); // minus 10 hours
```

Comment: this really worked out well, thanks. i will go through the manual too. Thanks again