# Formatting String in PHP

Tags: php, web

I am trying to display numbers retrieved from the database, in a specific format in a text box.
There are two ways in which the numbers can be displayed.

- When the total numbers are 10 
  in database (4608061019)      Expected output 46-0806-1019
- When the total numbers are 13
  in database (4608061019100)   Expected output 46-0806-1019-100

My progress so far:

While saving the value into the database I am using
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$string); // to make sure all hardcoded "-" are removed while storing.

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert from MySQL datetime to another format with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/convert-from-mysql-datetime-to-another-format-with-php)

Comment: It doesn't look like a datetime; most probably, these are CCNs.

Answer (score 1):

Easy! If you are sure that there are only these two options, then you can do this way:

1. Convert the number to an array of numbers:

   ```
   $number = str_split($number);
   ```
2. Check the length:

   ```
   if (count($number) == 10)
       $number = $number[0] . $number[1] . "-" . $number[2] . $number[3] . $number[4] . $number[5] . "-" . $number[6] . $number[7] . $number[8] . $number[9];
   else if (count($number) == 13)
       $number = $number[0] . $number[1] . "-" . $number[2] . $number[3] . $number[4] . $number[5] . "-" . $number[6] . $number[7] . $number[8] . $number[9] . "-" . $number[10] . $number[11] . $number[12];
   ```
3. Return the number:

   ```
   return $number;
   ```

The full function here:

```
function tokenize($number)
{
    $number = str_split($number);
    if (count($number) == 10)
        $number = $number[0] . $number[1] . "-" . $number[2] . $number[3] . $number[4] . $number[5] . "-" . $number[6] . $number[7] . $number[8] . $number[9];
    else if (count($number) == 13)
        $number = $number[0] . $number[1] . "-" . $number[2] . $number[3] . $number[4] . $number[5] . "-" . $number[6] . $number[7] . $number[8] . $number[9] . "-" . $number[10] . $number[11] . $number[12];
    return $number;
}
```

#### Output

```
echo tokenize(4608061019);
echo tokenize(4608061019100);

Output

46-0806-1019
46-0806-1019-100
```

#### Fiddle: http://codepad.viper-7.com/EVWeFR

Answer (score 1):

One possible (regex-using) approach:

```
$str = '4608061019';
$formatted = preg_replace(
  '/(^\d{2}|\d{4})(?!$)/', '$1-', $str);
// 46-0806-1019
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/232100). This function doesn't check the string's length - it just adds a hyphen after each relevant sequence of symbols (2 right after the beginning, 4 afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution:

```
$parts = array(2,4,4,3);
$string = "4608061019100";
$i = 0;
$newString = '';
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    $newString.=substr($string, $i, $part) ."-";
    $i = $i+$part;
}
$newString = rtrim($newString, "-");
```

Output is:

```
string '46-0806-1019-100' (length=16)
```

Works for `46-0806-1019` too.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
//$number = '4608061019';
$number = '4608061019100';



function formatImportantNumber($theNumber){
    $formatedNumber = '';
    if(strlen($theNumber)==10){
    //46-0806-1019
        $formatedNumber = substr($theNumber, 0, 2).'-'.substr($theNumber, 2, 4).'-'.substr($theNumber, 6, 4); 
    }elseif(strlen($theNumber)==13){
    //46-0806-1019-100
        $formatedNumber = substr($theNumber, 0, 2).'-'.substr($theNumber, 2, 4).'-'.substr($theNumber, 6, 4).'-'.substr($theNumber, 10, 3); 
    }else{
        die('Invalid number formated')
    }


    return $formatedNumber;
}

echo formatImportantNumber($number);
```