# Changing the date format before inserting it into database

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm using the below code to take the date input from the user:

`<p>Start Date: <input id="start" name="start_Date" type="date" /></p>`

I'm processing this input through PHP script and inserting into a database as follows:

`startDate = '{$f['start_Date']}'`

This inserts the date in the database in yyyy-mm-dd. How to change this to mm/dd/yyyy format before inserting it into the database.

Comment: `mm/dd/yyyy` is not mysql's date format. Do you mean you want to output as that?

Comment: yes, I don't mind even if it is stored as a text(I'll change the column type to text from date in db if needed). I want it to be in mm/dd/yyyy format

Comment: You should store it as a date then modify its display on output. You are going to lose all date functions by making it text/string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from MySQL datetime to another format with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/convert-from-mysql-datetime-to-another-format-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

mysql date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`,

so before inserting the code, use `strtotime()` and convert the date to mysql format.

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['start_Date']));
```

For more format's(All possible formats), see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Create a datetime object out of your date, then format it as you wish.

http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.format.php

```
$myDate = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
echo $myDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```