# Formatting time when getting from sql

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to Format my Date and time but i do not know how to at the moment i am getting a output like `2015-12-16 02:24:33` but i would like to get somthing like this `8th August 2015 03:12:46 PM` how can i do this

```
$note_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `user_id` = $my_id");
while ($run_note = mysql_fetch_assoc($note_query))
        {
          $note_date = $run_note['Note_added_dat'];
          echo $note_date;
         }
```

Comment: one option: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Please avoid using deprecated `mysql_*` functions, use PDO / MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way to format your date using php date formats.

```
   $note_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `user_id` = $my_id");
   while ($run_note = mysql_fetch_assoc($note_query)){
      $note_date = $run_note['Note_added_dat'];
      $formated_date=date("jS F Y H:i:s A",strtotime($note_date));
      echo $note_date;
      echo $formated_date;
     }
```

See other formats :http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

**EDIT:** As per comment

```
$date='2015-12-16 02:24:33';
$formated_date=date("jS M Y H:i:s A",strtotime($date));
echo $formated_date;
```

Comment: can i make `December` Display Like `Dec`

Comment: @jake123, See my edit for your desired result. please check out the other date formates from http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, it will help you to format as you like. Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL `Date_Format` function:

```
select date_format(date_column,'%D %M %Y %r')
```

SQL Fiddle Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/35713

For more information for date formats : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Answer (score 1):

See this SO post for your question.
[Convert from MySQL datetime to another format with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/convert-from-mysql-datetime-to-another-format-with-php).

Also, please check out the PHP Documentation (I recommend reading all the way through it). You really should NOT be using the mysql extension as it is deprecated. Instead use myqli or PDO.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: link only answers are discouraged

Answer (score 1):

using the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function of `php`

```
echo date('jS F Y H:i:s A',strtotime('2015-12-16 02:24:33'));
```