# Letters in Specific DateTime - How to Parse

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I am getting a DateTime from an API that is formatted as such:

> 2015-11-27T21:05:03Z

What does the T mean? Does it just a signify that the time is next in the string? Through some searching I found that the Z might mean the zulu time zone or UTC+0:00. Is this even right? How would I go about parsing this in PHP to get it into a SQL DateTime? I bet this is a basic question but I'm having trouble even coming up with good search terms for google.

Comment: This [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/convert-from-mysql-datetime-to-another-format-with-php) and [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) should answer your questions.

Comment: I already know how to format dates based on what is provided in the documentation that you linked. The T and Z in my date is throwing me off and is not mentioned in either link.

Comment: Sorry, I could have picked better links. `T` means the time is next according to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), and `Z` means [Zulu time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones).

Comment: Okay great thanks! I figured it was something simple but just didn't know how to google this kind of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Z` is a special UTC designator, times are expressed in UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) uses it for the zero UTC offset.
When a time zone designator is used, `T` is used as a delimiter also its and a valid time expression.

Using php `strtotime` should do it. 
Try

```
strtotime('2015-11-27T21:05:03Z');
```

[PHP datetime formats compound](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php)

Comment: Thank you! I was more concerened about what the T and Z actually meant - answered above. But this helps!

Answer (score 1):

According to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations), T delimits date and time.