# How to convert time format Mysql to hours/minutes

Tags: php, time

I have a time format from mysql who looks like this : **07:22:46.5714**

And I want to display instead **07h23min**

I have searched php already existing function for this but it seems like I have to wrote one, how can I do this ?

Comment: you can use substring to catch "07" and "22"

Comment: do you want to round minutes?

Comment: you can use explode by ":"

Comment: which existing function do you use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/convert-from-mysql-datetime-to-another-format-with-php

Comment: @Bhautik the link worked to round the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options :

you can format the time using MySQL function [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) like this :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(mydate, '%kh%imin') FROM table
```

The other solution is to use php function [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.explode.php) like this :

```
$timeParts = explode(':', '07:22:46.5714');
$timeString = $timeParts[0] . 'h' . $time[1] . 'min'
```

Comment: Dateformat function was really efficient! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily. Check the below code.

```
$time = strtotime('07:22:46.5714');
$display = Date('h\hi\m\i\n',$time);
var_dump($display);
```

Output is - `07h22min`

Answer (score 1):

```
function myPersonalDateFormat($time){
    $t = strtotime($time);
    return sprintf("%sh%smin", date("H", $t), date("i", $t));
}

// This will print 07h22min
echo  myPersonalDateFormat('07:22:46.5714');
```

This is using a combination [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), that converts your string to a timestamp, [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), that allows to print a given timestamp to a specifide format (so you can get only the hours part or minutes, and [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) that returns a string according to the given format `%sh%smin`(%s is a placeholder for "string").

Comment: I tested it, it works as well, I like the fact that you made it with a function, I'm gonna save it, it will probably gonna be useful later, thank you!