# How to print date separetly like day or month or year?

Tags: php, datetime

I want to print date separety like only day or year or month.
like: just month not the rest of date time in sql

I do print date like below and its same format in my database

> datetime  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

2018-10-27 19:09:49

Thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from MySQL datetime to another format with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/convert-from-mysql-datetime-to-another-format-with-php)

Comment: REad the Documentation,, http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: My question is not about date format, I need explode function why duplicate ? @Sanu0786

Comment: Thanks that link helps @ArtisticPhoenix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result to the variable and With PHP you should use an explode() function to achieve the result.

To split the given string it's better to separate date from time by 'space' character, and then use again the explode() function on the given date with a 'dash' symbol.

So it may looks like this:

```
$first_split = explode(' ', your_datetime_variable);
$date = $first_split[0]; //2018-10-27
$time = $first_split[1]; //19:09:49
$second_split = explode('-', $date);
$year = $second_split[0]; //2018
$month = $second_split[1]; //10
$day = $second_split[2]; //27
```

Comment: Thanks bud usefull function

Answer (score 2):

you can display date,month,year using below code

for year

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "2018-11-01 5:11:10");output:2018
```

for Month

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "2017-06-15 5:11:10");output:6
```

for Day

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM "2017-06-15 5:11:10");Otput:15
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as everything can be achieved using SQL.