# How to convert the date record wth DATE type in mysql database,

Tags: php, mysql, date, formatting

Honestly I'm just a novice in coding using PHP and Mysql.
I just want to know if someone could help me how to convert the date record from mysql database table with a 'DATE' type. Currently, I could display the default format (yyyy-mm-dd). But I would like to display it like 'Jan-20-2020'.

Here is the part of the code that I have already did that displays the default format. 
https://www.screencast.com/t/WOou3TAsT
Please help me what code should I add to convert and display it in character format like the above example.

Heres the current result that I'm displaying;
https://www.screencast.com/t/zcWp8sZ34

Thanks for reading and appreciate any help.

Regards,
Melo Villanueva

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert from MySQL datetime to another format with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/convert-from-mysql-datetime-to-another-format-with-php)

Comment: I would handle this in client side code, such that the date is correct formatted according to the locale or preferences of the viewer

Answer (score 0):

`echo date('M-m-Y', strtotime('2019-01-01'));` will solve your problem, you can check the manual: [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), for full explanations.

Answer (score -1):

Since you´re using mySQL database, try this:

Use STR_TO_DATE() method from MySQL to convert. The syntax is as follows wherein we are using format specifiers. The format specifiers begin with %.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(yourDateColumnName,'%d.%m.%Y') as anyVariableName FROM yourTableName;
```

To understand the above syntax, let us create a table. The query to create a table is as follows.

```
mysql> create table ConvertIntoDateFormat
   -> (
   -> Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   -> LoginDate varchar(30),
   -> PRIMARY KEY(Id)
   -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.47 sec)

Insert some records in the table using insert command. The query is as follows −

mysql> insert into ConvertIntoDateFormat(LoginDate) values('11.01.2019');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> insert into ConvertIntoDateFormat(LoginDate) values('10.04.2017');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.16 sec)

mysql> insert into ConvertIntoDateFormat(LoginDate) values('21.10.2016');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> insert into ConvertIntoDateFormat(LoginDate) values('26.09.2018');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.14 sec)

mysql> insert into ConvertIntoDateFormat(LoginDate) values('25.12.2012');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.17 sec)
```

Display all records from the table using select statement. The query is as follows−

```
mysql> select *from ConvertIntoDateFormat;
```

The following is the output.

```
+----+------------+
| Id | LoginDate  |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 11.01.2019 |
|  2 | 10.04.2017 |
|  3 | 21.10.2016 |
|  4 | 26.09.2018 |
|  5 | 25.12.2012 |
+----+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The following is the query to format the date to YYYY-MM-DD.

```
mysql> select str_to_date(LoginDate,'%d.%m.%Y') as DateFormat from ConvertIntoDateFormat;
Here is the output.

+------------+
| DateFormat |
+------------+
| 2019-01-11 |
| 2017-04-10 |
| 2016-10-21 |
| 2018-09-26 |
| 2012-12-25 |
+------------+
```

5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
You can also use DATE_FORMAT() method for the same purpose. The query is as follows

```
mysql> select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(LoginDate,'%d.%m.%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') as DateFormat from
   -> ConvertIntoDateFormat;
```

The following is the output−

```
+------------+
| DateFormat |
+------------+
| 2019-01-11 |
| 2017-04-10 |
| 2016-10-21 |
| 2018-09-26 |
| 2012-12-25 |
+------------+
```

5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Culled from: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql-date-format-to-convert-dd-mm-yy-to-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: This is back to front. The OP is using a DATE data type